# Number of roots counting multiplicities

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the number of roots, counting multiplicities, of the equation $2z^{5}-6z^{2}+z+1=0$ in the annulus $1\leq |z|<2$.
I use Rouches theorem to solve this.
I choose $f(z)=-6z^{2}$ and $g(z)=2z^{5}+z+1$ so I get first condition $|f|>|g|$ for all $z \in $ $contour:(|z|=1)$and $f$ and $f+g$ have same number of zeros counting multiplicity so I get $2$ zeros so as far I consider my contour as $|z|=1$ but answer is 3 ?
Need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see where the annulus came into your calculation.  Where is the contour $|z|=2$ showing up?

Comment: Yup contour is annual shape can we omit second half. How to deal with this @Michael

Comment: Look at the contours $|z|=1$ and $|z|=2$ and subtract the roots.

Comment: Mean (number zeros in |Z|=2) - (number zeros in |Z|=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got $2$ zeros in the circle $|z| \le 1$. You want to count the number of zeros in the **annulus**  $1\leq |z|<2$. So you also need to count the zreos in the circle $|z| < 2$. By substrating $2$ to this quantity you will obtain 3. Tell me if you can't obtain the number of zeros in the other domain.